# fail to online install sbt (following official guide)

Tags: scala, ubuntu, sbt

on Ubuntu16.04,  from this offical page: 
https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

what I got:

```
fino@envy:bin$ echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
[sudo] password for fino: 
deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /

fino@envy:bin$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
Executing: /tmp/tmp.YqbI7qVhAP/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv
2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
gpg: requesting key 642AC823 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com

?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found
```

I tried both direct connect to internet or "export all_proxy=sock5h://ip:port" since I am in mainland:-)

Comment: Can't say anything about `deb` installation, but simply downloading the `.zip`, unpacking it, and adding `/sbt/bin` subdirectory to `PATH` never failed me.

Comment: thank.  I can do it this way.  but still want to find a answer why official website's guide not working for me;  or not working for others also.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy ? You can add this to the command line `-keyserver-options http-proxy=<myProxy>`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I'm pretty sure I am not behind any firewall.

Comment: Whoops, actually I have a similar looking but different issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983144/error-installing-sbt-on-ubuntu-18-04-gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-invalid-ar . They might be related but probably not.

Answer (score 0):

```
gpg: requesting key 642AC823 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com

?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found
```

You're failing to connect to `keyserver.ubuntu.com` to verify the public key, so I don't think this is an issue with sbt or its distribution.
I'd suggest you download the deb file manually, or find out some other key server available to you.